# How can I adjust buffer settings when using xbootmgr?

Tags: windows, performance

I am trying to analyze our clients which suffer from long boot & logon delays, so I installed Windows Performance Toolkit.

This is the command line I have used to capture a startup:

`xbootmgr -trace boot -numRuns 1 -traceflags base+latency+dispatcher -stackwalk profile+cswitch+readythread -noTraceFlagsInFileName -postBootDelay 240 -resultPath C:\Traces`

When analyzing the traces with "Windows Performance Analyzer" I receive:

[image]

I know how to adjust the buffer settings when using `xperf` which are the paramters `-bufferSize, -maxBuffers, -minBuffers`. However this parameters are not valid for `xbootmgr`.

So how can I adjust the buffers? Or what whould be the corresponding `xperf` command line? What's the difference anyway between these poorly documented tools?

Comment: this is not really possible. Use WPRUI and select Boot transition. it should use a higher buffer.

Comment: have you tried WPRUI? Does it work?